# Oracle Apex - How to export all applications using APEXExport 18.1 on Centos 7

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I manually export All Oracle Apex applications using APEXExport utility ?

- **Versions tested together** (should be applicable with any version)

  - Oracle Apex 18.1
  - Oracle Express Database 11.2.0.2
  - Ords 3.x
  - Linux Centos 7.x

Answer (score 1):

### **HOW**

**Set Variables**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/java/bin
```

**Go To Utilities directory** ( must )

```
cd /u01/download/apex/utilities
```

**The following will export all applications in My Apex Schema.**

```
java oracle/apex/APEXExport -db www.apexserver.com:1521:xe -user my_workspace -password my_workspace -instance
```